# Nginx too many open files DDOS

Tags: nginx, denial-of-service

Im having an issue with ddos at the moment. My web server is behind a reverse-proxy (cloudflare), which I know shouldn't be relied on with their free plan. Cloudflare is in under-attack-mode, which causes visitors to complete a browser check. Accessing the site via direct IP will only redirect them. I'm using nginx's request throttling feature, but this doesn't seem to help as the attacker is using a huge proxy list. There's no huge red flags in the request, so im not sure whether a WAF would help. What's interesting, though, is that when I look in the error log; I see that what's causing the DOS is the following error (which the file is completely filled with)

```
2015/09/03 19:22:12 [crit] 3427#0: accept4() failed (24: Too many open files)
```

Im thinking now that they're attacking via the direct IP, but the redirect isnt enough to stop them from making me reach my open file limit. Is there anything I can do to stop this?

Thanks

EDIT: I don't believe they're attacking the IP directly because the software I have running on the site still detected the massive amounts of traffic that the attacker caused.

EDIT: Here's a few lines of the traffic he's spamming. Would  cloudflare's out-of-the-box WAF block this?

```
87.135.112.116 - - [05/Sep/2015:14:47:53 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.0" 200 15767 "-" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; Media Center PC 6.0)"

113.22.35.98 - - [05/Sep/2015:14:47:53 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.0" 200 15767 "-" "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux i686; Ubuntu/14.10) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16"

2.50.56.236 - - [05/Sep/2015:14:47:54 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.0" 200 15767 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.81 Safari/537.36"

93.170.133.26 - - [05/Sep/2015:14:47:54 +0200] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.0" 200 15767 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0"
```

Comment: Cloudflare provides a list of IP's you can let through from their proxies.  Perhaps create iptables rules to allow them to your ports 80/443 only.  How many files do you have open?   sysctl fs.file-nr

Comment: The issue isnt with cloudflare, I dont think. I think they're accessing the site directly via the system's ip, not cloudflare.

Comment: That is why I am suggesting you only let in Cloudflare and nobody else, since you mentioned people may be going directly to your server IP.  This should be apparent in your logs.  remote_addr vs. cloudflare IP header.

Comment: oh, I see. I'll give it a shot and edit this

Comment: "Cloudflare provides a list of IP's you can let through from their proxies. Perhaps create iptables rules to allow them to your ports 80/443 only."

Good possible suggestion. Just including a link to our IP ranges: https://www.cloudflare.com/ips

Comment: edited my post. I don't believe they're attacking the IP directly because the software I have running on the site still detected the massive amounts of traffic that the attacker caused.

Comment: would cloudflare's WAF help prevent this, possibly?

Answer (score 2):

Too many open files means that you have hit the ulimit variable for nginx defined by the default in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` (if using RHEL-based linux). What this means is that nginx has too many open connections and can not serve out any more requests. You can correct this by increasing the following variable:

```
worker_rlimit_nofile <enter value here>;
```

you can replace the information in the angle brackets with the new value (the default is 1024). This will increase your open file count (and therefore increase your open connection count, since each connection is a file).

Three things:

1. figure out your limits for your server (this will depend on the number of cpus and amount of ram you have).
2. the `worker_rlimit_nofile` goes at the top of your configuration file right below "worker_processes" variable.
3. once you set the variable in the file, you are going to need to restart nginx.

Comment: while increasing the limit could be a temporary solution, it doesnt really fix my problem.

Comment: agreed, I wasn't saying it was a permanent solution. The fix for that particular error (ignoring the DOS portion) is to increase the worker_rlimit value. fixing the problem is going to take using something like a WAF or paying for cloudflare's paid services. Also, you could get other DDoS protection services, but it all depends on your budget. Another way to deal with it is to scale out. Put your nginx server behind a load balancer and add more nginx servers behind it. However, that more depends on your environment and how it is architected.

Comment: i see, well I was thinking of upgrading to cloudflare pro and using their WAF. unfortunately they dont allow custom rules unless you have the business plan. do you think they'd detect your run-of-the-mill http flood? I want to stop it as far up the line as possible

Comment: added an example of the traffic he's creating from my access log